# How to check for the existence of an xml element/attribute through batch file commands

Tags: xml, batch-file, command-line

I have to insert an xml element into an xml file through batch file. After lot of research, I was able to achieve using the below code. But if the element/line already exists, I should not add it.

My xml file looks like as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <PastFiles Iterations="1" MaxTimeFrame="20min">
    <FileDefinition OrderNum="1" Directory="LOG" PurgeInSubdirectories="No" FilePattern=".\. 
    (txt|log|html|xml|csv)" MaxSize="10MB" PastFilesOlderThan="10day"/>
 </PastFiles>
```

I was able to insert xml element - "<FileDefinition OrderNum="14" Directory="TRACE" PurgeInSubdirectories="Yes" DeleteEmptySubDirs="Yes" FilePattern="*" PastFilesOlderThan="28day"
before the end PastFiles tag, but if the element already exists I should not add it.

```
@echo off
setlocal

>"newfile1.xml" (
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("LogConfig_BP.xml") do (
    set "line=%%I"  
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        
    if not "!line!"=="!line:/PastFiles=!" (     
            echo ^<FileDefinition OrderNum="14" Directory="TRACE" PurgeInSubdirectories="Yes" DeleteEmptySubDirs="Yes" FilePattern="*" PastFilesOlderThan="28day"/^>        
        )
         endlocal
         echo %%I
    )
 )
 type "newfile1.xml"
  pause
```

Hence, I need to check either the entire line matches or even the starting part - <FileDefinition OrderNum="14" matches before inserting the tag? Please help !!!

Comment: ruby, perl, python all have xml parsers. Or use xmlstarlet.

Comment: Please read "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)".

Answer (score 3):

Your research somehow failed to come up with the strong advice, often articulated in these columns, that you should never attempt to process XML as text directly, without using an XML parser. It's a recipe for making your code vulnerable to trivial variations in the XML such as changing order of attributes or adding whitespace, and for generating ill-formed XML e..g by failing to escape special characters correctly. A very large proportion of problems reported on this site relating to unreadable XML have this as their root cause.

Use XSLT for the transformation, and invoke the XSLT from a shell command. Ideally, use ant or gradle to control the processing pipeline rather than bash.

Alternatively, for simple manipulations, there are tools like xmlstarlet or Saxon Gizmo that can be invoked from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [xpath.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat)

```
call xpath.bat xml1.xml "//FileDefinition/@OrderNum1"|findstr "^" >nul 2>&1 || (
  echo has NOT file definition
) && (
  echo has file definition
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to edit XML merely with native Batch functions is an almost impossible task. An XML parser, like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel), would save you lots of headaches!

```
xidel -s LogConfig_BP.xml -e "x:replace-nodes(//FileDefinition[last()],function($x){$x,if ($x[@OrderNum='14']) then () else <FileDefinition OrderNum='14' Directory='TRACE' PurgeInSubdirectories='Yes' DeleteEmptySubDirs='Yes' FilePattern='*' PastFilesOlderThan='28day'/>})" --output-format=xml --output-declaration="<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" --output-node-indent
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PastFiles Iterations="1" MaxTimeFrame="20min">
  <FileDefinition OrderNum="1" Directory="LOG" PurgeInSubdirectories="No" FilePattern=".\. &#xA;  (txt|log|html|xml|csv)" MaxSize="10MB" PastFilesOlderThan="10day"/>
  <FileDefinition OrderNum="14" Directory="TRACE" PurgeInSubdirectories="Yes" DeleteEmptySubDirs="Yes" FilePattern="*" PastFilesOlderThan="28day"/>
</PastFiles>
```

Alternatively you can use [computed constructors](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-computedConstructors):

```
xidel -s LogConfig_BP.xml -e "x:replace-nodes(//FileDefinition[last()],function($x){$x,if ($x[@OrderNum='14']) then () else element FileDefinition {attribute OrderNum {'14'}, attribute Directory {'TRACE'}, attribute PurgeInSubdirectories {'Yes'}, attribute DeleteEmptySubDirs {'Yes'}, attribute FilePattern {'*'}, attribute PastFilesOlderThan {'28day'}}})" --output-format=xml --output-declaration="<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" --output-node-indent
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PastFiles Iterations="1" MaxTimeFrame="20min">
  <FileDefinition OrderNum="1" Directory="LOG" PurgeInSubdirectories="No" FilePattern=".\. &#xA;  (txt|log|html|xml|csv)" MaxSize="10MB" PastFilesOlderThan="10day"/>
  <FileDefinition OrderNum="14" Directory="TRACE" PurgeInSubdirectories="Yes" DeleteEmptySubDirs="Yes" FilePattern="*" PastFilesOlderThan="28day"/>
</PastFiles>
```

Prettified query for better readability (including the necessary escape-characters):

```
xidel -s LogConfig_BP.xml -e ^"^
  x:replace-nodes(^
    //FileDefinition[last()],^
    function($x){^
      $x,^
      if ($x[@OrderNum='14']) then^
        ()^
      else^
        element FileDefinition {^
          attribute OrderNum {'14'},^
          attribute Directory {'TRACE'},^
          attribute PurgeInSubdirectories {'Yes'},^
          attribute DeleteEmptySubDirs {'Yes'},^
          attribute FilePattern {'*'},^
          attribute PastFilesOlderThan {'28day'}^
        }^
    }^
  )^
" --output-format=xml --output-declaration="<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" --output-node-indent
```

[Playground](https://www.videlibri.de/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?compatibility=Enable+all+extensions&data=%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%221.0%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3CPastFiles+Iterations%3D%221%22+MaxTimeFrame%3D%2220min%22%3E%0D%0A++%3CFileDefinition+OrderNum%3D%221%22+Directory%3D%22LOG%22+PurgeInSubdirectories%3D%22No%22+FilePattern%3D%22..+%0D%0A++(txt%7Clog%7Chtml%7Cxml%7Ccsv)%22+MaxSize%3D%2210MB%22+PastFilesOlderThan%3D%2210day%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FPastFiles%3E&extract=x%3Areplace-nodes(%0D%0A++%2F%2FFileDefinition%5Blast()%5D%2C%0D%0A++function(%24x)%7B%0D%0A++++%24x%2C%0D%0A++++if+(%24x%5B%40OrderNum%3D%2714%27%5D)+then+()%0D%0A++++else+%3CFileDefinition+OrderNum%3D%2714%27+Directory%3D%27TRACE%27+PurgeInSubdirectories%3D%27Yes%27+DeleteEmptySubDirs%3D%27Yes%27+FilePattern%3D%27*%27+PastFilesOlderThan%3D%2728day%27%2F%3E%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0A)+%3D%3E+serialize(%7B%27indent%27%3Atrue()%2C%27omit-xml-declaration%27%3Afalse()%7D)%2C%0D%0A%27%27%2C%0D%0Ax%3Areplace-nodes(%0D%0A++%2F%2FFileDefinition%5Blast()%5D%2C%0D%0A++function(%24x)%7B%0D%0A++++%24x%2C%0D%0A++++if+(%24x%5B%40OrderNum%3D%2714%27%5D)+then%0D%0A++++++()%0D%0A++++else+%0D%0A++++++element+FileDefinition+%7B%0D%0A++++++++attribute+OrderNum+%7B%2714%27%7D%2C%0D%0A++++++++attribute+Directory+%7B%27TRACE%27%7D%2C%0D%0A++++++++attribute+PurgeInSubdirectories+%7B%27Yes%27%7D%2C%0D%0A++++++++attribute+DeleteEmptySubDirs+%7B%27Yes%27%7D%2C%0D%0A++++++++attribute+FilePattern+%7B%27*%27%7D%2C%0D%0A++++++++attribute+PastFilesOlderThan+%7B%2728day%27%7D%0D%0A++++++%7D%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0A)+%3D%3E+serialize(%7B%27indent%27%3Atrue()%2C%27omit-xml-declaration%27%3Afalse()%7D)%0D%0A&extract-kind=xquery3.1&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&input-format=auto&dot-notation=unambiguous).